# Network ping responses with very large times and other weirdness

Tags: linux, networking

I've been having a problem with a computer on a remote network and have been trying to figure out why it keeps having network issues (I would normally try to be on-site, but I am temporarily unable to travel).  It has an RTL8169-SC network controlle, and I have checked various logs but nothing appears to be acting up.  It is attached to a Cisco switch (semi-smart, it has a web config).  I have confirmed that no conflicts exist.

I have tried using the kernel's r8169 module, and also swapped in the Realtek sourced version.  The latter kept the unit online a lot longer than the one from the kernel, but I still see the same problem.

Here's a sample of the ping responses I'm getting.  They cycle from getting a pile of responses in a burst (with the super-long times) and eventually failing to reach the host.  I'm not sure whether this might be a problem with the computer (probably?) or the switch.  Other devices haven't had problems like this too.  It looks like something (again, either the computer or switch) are buffering a lot of the ping requests and eventually they're being transmitted back.  Any thoughts/tricks/questions are appreciated.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18655 ttl=64 time=136025 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18656 ttl=64 time=135026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18657 ttl=64 time=134026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18658 ttl=64 time=133026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18659 ttl=64 time=132026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18660 ttl=64 time=131026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18661 ttl=64 time=130026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18662 ttl=64 time=129026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18663 ttl=64 time=128026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18664 ttl=64 time=127026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18665 ttl=64 time=126026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18666 ttl=64 time=125026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18719 ttl=64 time=72013 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18720 ttl=64 time=71013 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18721 ttl=64 time=70013 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18722 ttl=64 time=69013 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18723 ttl=64 time=68013 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18724 ttl=64 time=67014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18725 ttl=64 time=66014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18726 ttl=64 time=65014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18727 ttl=64 time=64014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18728 ttl=64 time=63014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18729 ttl=64 time=62014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18730 ttl=64 time=61014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18783 ttl=64 time=8003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18784 ttl=64 time=7003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18785 ttl=64 time=6003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18786 ttl=64 time=5003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18787 ttl=64 time=4003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18788 ttl=64 time=3003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18789 ttl=64 time=2003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.161: icmp_seq=18790 ttl=64 time=1003 ms
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18826 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18827 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18828 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18830 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18831 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18832 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18834 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18835 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18836 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18838 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18839 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18840 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18842 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18843 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.158 icmp_seq=18844 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: Are the response actually taking that long, or is it a display anomaly?

Comment: Is it just that one host or is it others? What happens if you ping this host from another host at the same time as the long response times? As quick thing to rule out the switch port, have you changed the port on the switch this host is plugged in to?

Comment: The responses are taking that long.  Most of the time you see Destination Host Unreachable, with gaps in the icmp_seq.  Suddenly a flood of responses come in with the times that they took to reply.

Comment: Also, switch ports have been changed and the switch has been changed with a 'dumb' switch to see if it made a difference.  I have tried pinging with different hosts and they have similar responses, but I haven't kept track of the responses to see if they all get them at the same time.  When the problem pops up again, I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: Try tracing what path your stuff follows through the net, e.g. with `traceroute` or similar. Then you can `ping` each on the way, and find out where ping times jump... (Those times are beyond ridiculous, something _very_ fishy is going on here... any local firewall doing "QoS" or such is perhaps holding back "unimportant" ICMP from a saturated Internet connection?)

Comment: I've been examining the problem unit from other systems on the same network.  Traceroute took a while, but only shows the target system as a hop (they're all on the same switch).  If I ping from multiple hosts to the target system, they get their responses at the same time.  I wondered what ping flooding might do, so I tried it.  The amount of time it took for the other systems to get their responses was much lower, so something (the target device?) appears to be something buffering the pings up.

Comment: As a side note, while ping flooding the target, I was able to ssh into the system.  I saw Send Q backups with netstat, but nothing overly interesting in dmesg (a NETDEV WATCHDOG on eth0 transmits, which might be a problem with the Realtek network controller).  I ran 'ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up' and now it is responding normally on the network.  More to check, but at least I can play around more with it when it happens again.

Comment: Try disabling Generic Receive Offload on the network interface (and possibly TCP Segmentation Offload as well). You will need [ethtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethtool) for this.